# Handling sub-arrays (one column array of multi col array)

Tags: arrays, vba, user-defined-functions

Question on handling sub-arrays (one column array of multi col array)

I send an RFR_array (100 rows, 1 col) to a function that calcs the discount rate.
I call “on the fly”:
    `for z is 1:100,    loop  TempArrayR(z, 1) = CreateDiscArray(RFR_array)(z, 1)   end for loop`

Now I make an array (100rows, 4 col)
I specify one col say “2” of the array. i.e. Here selected "USD" or CurrNumber is 2, to construct discount factor using just column 2 of the larger multicurrency array. Can’t find right code, here where
I call “on the fly”: 
    `for z is 1:100,    loop  TempArrayR(z, 1) = CreateDiscArray(RFR_array(,2))(z, 1)   end for loop`

Full code follows:

```
     Dim CurrNumber As Double
    If Curr = "USD" Then
    CurrNumber = 2
ElseIf Curr = "CAD" Then
    CurrNumber = 1
ElseIf Curr = "GBP" Then
    CurrNumber = 3
ElseIf Curr = "EUR" Then
    CurrNumber = 4
End If

    Dim RFR_array_one_curr() As Variant
    Dim RFR_array() As Variant
    Dim q As Integer
    For q = 0 To 100 Step 1
    If q = 0 Then RFR_array(0, 1) = 0
    If q > 0 Then RFR_array(q, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(RFR_Array_all, q, CurrNumber - 1)
    Next q
    RFR_array_one_curr = RFR_array


Dim z As Integer
For z = 0 To zDim Step 1
    If z = 0 Then TempArrayR(0, 1) = 1
    If z > 0 Then TempArrayR(z, 1) = CreateDiscArray(RFR_array_one_curr)(z, 1)
Next z
Disc_array = TempArrayR
```

`

Error at CreateDiscArray(RFR_array_one_curr)is a reference error.

`

```
Function CreateDiscArray(RFR_array As Range)
' INPUT: a column of risk-free rates one per year [1,100].
    Dim MyArray() As Variant
    MyArray = RFR_array.Value
    Dim xDimRate As Integer
    xDimRate = UBound(MyArray, 1)
    ReDim TempArray(LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray), LBound(MyArray, 2) To UBound(MyArray, 2)) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To xDimRate Step 1
        TempArray(i, 1) = DiscFact(MyArray(i, 1), i)
    Next i
    CreateDiscArray = TempArray
End Function
```

`

Comment: Please show your real relevant code and the code for CreateDiscArray()

Comment: Are you trying to extract a 1-dimensional array from a 2-dimensional array so that you can send it to a function? In VBA there is no real shortcut to reading the values in the target column into a properly dimensioned (or redimensioned) variant or array variable. 3 or 4 lines of code with a for loop is enough. Alternatively, you could rewrite `CreateDiscArray()` so that it can handle either 1-dimensional or 2-dimensional arrays, with an optional parameter saying which column to use in the 2-dimensional case.

Comment: Yes, I'm attempting just that.Will try the increasing capability of the subfunction that you suggest - many thanks

Comment: John, when using a loop to create the extraction, i use this code: `Dim RFR_array() As Variant
Dim q As Integer
For q = 0 To 100 Step 1
    If q = 0 Then RFR_array(0, 1) = 0
    If q > 0 Then RFR_array(q, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(RFR_Array_all, q, CurrNumber - 1)
Next q  `             but then when i call on `CreateDiscArray(RFR_array) ` there is a ByRef error. Do i need to use .Value? How does this syntax work, I find nothing online.